# Filter by string length (number of characters)

Tags: excel, filter

I am currently working with a table that contains a code in one column and its description in another. The bigger (longer) the code, the more specific its description. For example:

```
1     = Personal expenses.
1.1   = Personal services associated with payroll.
1.1.1 = Salaries of the people in the payroll.
```

I want to select only the rows of the table that have a maximum of **3** digits (not counting full stops) in their code. Using advanced filters in Excel, I tried to use a couple of wildcards defined on the code column, that is `?` OR `???` as needed in different rows.

However, this advanced filter seems to take the wildcard as a reference of the minimum number of characters to be included in the final table, so I end up with the same list I had to begin with.

When removing one condition, and using only `???` I end up with the list:

```
1.1   = Personal services associated with payroll.
1.1.1 = Salaries of the people in the payroll.
```

Thus confirming what I had already thought.

Does anyone know how I can appropriately filter this table the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try: *does not contain* `??????`

Comment: The first <>??????? works, however I keep having higher order codes. When adding the extra ?? to the filtering condition it stops working, and keeps extracting the same codes as the first does not contain.

Comment: for example: I have 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, as codes of certain variables. if I use <>????? I get the table containing the variables with codes 1, 1.1, 1.1.1.1. If I try to add two more ??, to get rid of the code 1.1.1.1, I end up getting the same list (i.e. 1, 1.1, 1.1.1.1.)

Comment: Keeping in mind that I am only interested in the codes 1 and 1.1 (for the sake of the example)

Comment: I was using "does not equal"... "does not contain" does the trick!!! <>*??????* Thanks a lot!